# Nativescript : How to show details of taped item from hard coded array list

Tags: android, data-binding, nativescript

i have a listview to show data from hardcoded array list and i need to make user able to click on any item to show the details of this item in another page , how can i do that ? i tried to create another array for details and make bindingContext and its working good but no data show when converting to details page as you can see here

thats my code :

main-view-model.js:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

function RegisterViewModel() {
    var viewModel = new Observable();
    viewModel.shows = [
        {name:"Reg1"},
        {name:"Reg2"},
        {name:"Reg3"},
        {name:"Reg4"},
        {name:"Reg5"},


    ];

    return viewModel;

}

exports.RegisterViewModel = RegisterViewModel;
```

main-page.js:

```
var RegisterViewModel = require("./main-view-model").RegisterViewModel;
var frameModule = require('ui/frame'); 


var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
function RegisterViewModel(args) {
var page = args.object;
page.bindingContext = RegisterViewModel();
}

exports.getInfo = function (args) {
     var navigationEntry = { 
     moduleName: "RegisterDetails",
     context: {info:args.view.bindingContext}
      }
      frameModule.topmost().navigate(navigationEntry);
    }

exports.loaded = function(args){
    args.object.bindingContext = viewModel;
}


exports.RegisterViewModel = RegisterViewModel;
```

main-page.xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page" loaded="loaded">

    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>

    <StackLayout class="p-20">

 <SearchBar id="searchBar" hint="Search" text="" clear="onClear" submit="onSubmit" />
<TabView>
   <TabView.items>
     <TabViewItem title="register">
       <TabViewItem.view>
           <ListView items="{{shows}}" tap="getInfo" >

            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{name}}" />

            </ListView.itemTemplate>

       </ListView>
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
     <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
       <TabViewItem.view>
          <Label text="Label in Tab2" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
   </TabView.items>
 </TabView>

    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

these for details:

RegisterDetails-model.js

```
    viewModel.shows = [
        {name:"Reg01"},
        {name:"Reg02"},
        {name:"Reg03"},
        {name:"Reg04"},
        {name:"Reg05"},

    ];
    return gotData;

}

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

RegisterDetails.js:

```
var gotData;
function pageLoaded(args) {
     var page = args.object;
     gotData = page.navigationContext.info;
     page.bindingContext={passedData:gotData}
    }

    exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

RegisterDetails.xml:

```
 <Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page" loaded="pageLoaded">

        <Page.actionBar>
            <ActionBar title="Register" icon="" class="action-bar">
            </ActionBar>
        </Page.actionBar>

        <StackLayout >
                    <Label text="{{name}}"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
```

but when i clicked on any item i go to register details but no data shows in page , and i received   this message error in console :

```
JS: Binding: Property: 'name' is invalid or does not exist. SourceProperty: 'name'
```

any help?

Comment: Too many abstractions - why not directly pass the value without creating a new complex object. apart from that, your details binding context is `{passedData:gotData}` but then you are trying to directly access `name` in your XML. Use `console.log` to see what the details binding context is.. perhaps `passedData.name`

Comment: Okay Nick ,what do you suggest ?

Comment: As suggested use `console.log(page.bindingContext)` to see your actual context is. Also, consider creating an Observable model. Here is how to pass context https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/blob/master/app/views/rovers/rover-photo-page.ts#L94-L103 and then received it at details page https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/blob/master/app/views/rovers/photo-details-page.ts#L45-L47 and finally reuse it in the XML https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/blob/master/app/views/rovers/photo-details-page.xml#L52

Comment: its using typescript , i am using javascript , Thank you for your time.